# 0 bytes on / remaining

Tags: linux, fedora

Столкнулся с такой проблемой

[image: сама проблема]

т.е. у меня (в теории) есть ещё ~700 МБ свободных, но их как бы нет.

дистрибутив - Fedora 22

linux - 4.1.6-201.fc22.x86_64

Comment: фрагментация, необходимость хранить журнал и прочее веселье физически никогда не дадут полностью заполнить обещанное пространство

Answer (score 2):

это не проблема. у вас просто закончилось свободное место в файловой системе.

последние пять процентов (по умолчанию) может заполнить только пользователь с идентификатором 0 (обычно эта учётная запись носит имя *root*).

для всех остальных пользователей этих пяти процентов, действительно, нет. правда — нет. на самом деле — нет.

---

подсказка:

выкладывать вывод команды `df /` лучше, всё-таки, не в виде огромного изображения, а просто текстом, благо там всего две строчки (причём одна из них — заголовки столбцов).

Comment: Дополню вредным советом: изменить процент зарезервированного места можно командой `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/XXX`, где 0 - 0%, т.е. место не резервируется совсем, а XXX - раздел диска. ВНИМАНИЕ! Для корневого раздела `/` лучший вариант - оставить всё как есть.